# Multicast Delegates - C++

Tags: unreal-engine4

I would like to receive a multicast event from the [LeapMotion plugin](https://github.com/leapmotion/LeapUnreal) in C++. From their documentation, they mention the following things:

```
> On Hand Grabbed Event called when a leap hand grab gesture is
> detected. Signature: const FLeapHandData&, Hand, see FLeapHandData
> 
> FLeapHandSignature OnHandGrabbed;
```

So in my .cpp file I added the following:

```
ALeapMotionGesture::ALeapMotionGesture()
{
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
    Leap = CreateDefaultSubobject<ULeapComponent>(TEXT("Leap"));
}

void ALeapMotionGesture::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    if (Leap != nullptr) {
        FScriptDelegate Delegate;
        Delegate.BindUFunction(this, FName("HandGrabbed"));
        Leap->OnHandGrabbed.Add(Delegate);
    }
}

void ALeapMotionGesture::HandGrabbed(const FLeapHandData& Hand) {
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Hand Grabbed"));
}
```

As it is the first time I'm using delegates in Unreal/C++, I would like to know how I could make it work?

It compiles fine however I do not receive any events.

Comment: Did you add `UFUNCTION()` on your function `HandGrabbed`?

Comment: Thanks, adding the UFUNCTION solved my issue!

Comment: Congratulations, If you accept my comment as answer, I would be more happy, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `UFUNCTION()` on your function `HandGrabbed`

Answer (score 3):

## Short Answer

Replace:

```cpp
void ALeapMotionGesture::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    if (Leap != nullptr) {
        FScriptDelegate Delegate;
        Delegate.BindUFunction(this, FName("HandGrabbed"));
        Leap->OnHandGrabbed.Add(Delegate);
    }
}
```

with:

```
void ALeapMotionGesture::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    if (Leap != nullptr) {
        Leap->OnHandGrabbed.AddDynamic(this, &ALeapMotionGesture::HandGrabbed);
    }
}
```

## Long Answer

[`ULeapComponent::OnHandGrabbed`](https://github.com/leapmotion/LeapUnreal/blob/856b3ec52031adb904bd9101b55074ef2687c096/Source/LeapMotion/Public/LeapComponent.h#L38) is a [`FLeapHandSignature`](https://github.com/leapmotion/LeapUnreal/blob/856b3ec52031adb904bd9101b55074ef2687c096/Source/LeapMotion/Public/LeapComponent.h#L13) which is declared with [`DECLARE_DYNAMIC_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_OneParam`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Delegates/Multicast).

The [LeapMotion README](https://github.com/leapmotion/LeapUnreal/blob/master/README.md#leap-component-events) says to consult the [Multi-cast documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Delegates/Multicast), but they are using dynamic delegates, so you actually need to read the [Dynamic Delegates documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Delegates/Dynamic). There you will see you should use the `AddDynamic` helper macro which generates the function name string for you.

Dynamic Delegates make use of helper macros that take care of generating the function name string for you.

From the [Dynamic Delegates doc](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Delegates/Dynamic):

> ## Dynamic Delegate Binding
>
> **BindDynamic( UserObject, FuncName )**
>
> Helper macro for calling BindDynamic() on dynamic delegates.
>   Automatically generates the function name string.
>
> **AddDynamic( UserObject, FuncName )**
>
> Helper macro for calling AddDynamic() on dynamic multi-cast delegates.
>   Automatically generates the function name string.
>
> **RemoveDynamic( UserObject, FuncName )**
>
> Helper macro for calling RemoveDynamic() on dynamic multi-cast
>   delegates. Automatically generates the function name string.

#### Side Note

Dynamic delegates are serialized, which sometimes results in unexpected behavior. For example, you can have delegate functions being called even though your code is no longer calling `AddDynamic` (because a serialized/saved actor serialized the results of your old code) or you might call `AddDynamic` even though the deserialization process already did that for you. To be safe, you probably should call `RemoveDynamic` before `AddDynamic`. Here's a snippet from FoliageComponent.cpp:

```cpp
// Ensure delegate is bound (just once)
CapsuleComponent->OnComponentBeginOverlap.RemoveDynamic(this, &AInteractiveFoliageActor::CapsuleTouched);
CapsuleComponent->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AInteractiveFoliageActor::CapsuleTouched);
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer Doug! In the end, both your piece of code and mine worked, the issue was what Protoss mentionned above - I forgot the UFUNCTION(). 

In this case, is it better to use the Multicast delegate as I did or switch to the Dynamic one as you proposed? (Or doesn't matter?)

Comment: Ah yeah, I've forgot UFUNCTION before as well. I'm actually not sure if one is better than the other. One nice thing about the AddDynamic is that it creates the function string for you.